# Is there a way to remove complex lines from an image with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, captcha, 2captcha

I have this 3 CAPTCHA images listed below and I want to make the text as clean as possible using opencv. Is there a pipeline that can achieve what I want?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is an example of what I want:

[image]

The biggest problem here is the color difference in letters. Any help would be appreciated!

Here are some parts from my code with all the image preprocessing

```py
raw_img = cv2.imread(image_file) #load image
img = cv2.cvtColor(raw_img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) #grayscale

_,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,240,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_TRUNC) #thresholding

thresh = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh) #invert black and white

#resizing image
resized = cv2.resize(img, (140, 60), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

img_gray = cv2.copyMakeBorder(resized, 10, 10, 10, 10, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=[255, 255, 255])

#blur
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (3, 3), 0)

# threshold again
_, img = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY or cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

cv2.imshow("Output", img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

However, if I apply this same code to the second iamge, for example, here is what I get:
[image]

I'm relatively new to OpenCV. I´m not sure if I am using the right approach here, if someone can help me showing other methods to clean this images I´d be greatful!

Comment: Have you searched for the issue? What did you get?

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code?

Comment: Just updated with some parts of my code, I hope it´s clearer now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the background seems to be the same across images you can subtract the background to find the foreground objects.
To obtain the background image you can run this code or use the image provided below.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('./test_img3.png')  # use the 3rd example
bg = np.repeat(img[:,0, np.newaxis], 180, axis=1)  # take the first column and repeat
cv2.imwrite('cap_bg.png', bg)
```

This gives the following image, which can then be used for subtraction:

[image: Captcha Background]

To find the lines the [Hough-Transformation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html) can be used. It can find lines in greyscale images and is very well explained in the openCV documentation.

```
bin_img = ((img - bg) > 0).astype(np.uint8) * 255  # subtract background and obtain binary image
bin_img = cv2.cvtColor(bin_img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)  # convert to greyscale image
lines = cv2.HoughLines(bin_img, 1, np.pi/360, 100)  # find lines
```

This output a list of all lines found in the image with the Hough transformation and the given parameters.
Now you only have to 'erase' each line by drawing a line in the background color over them.
You need to play around with the parameters, but I hope this can help for a start.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution! Very clever! But how exactly should I draw the lines using the background color? Can you enlighten me? :)

Comment: I was thinking using cv2.line() function to draw each line found from HoughLinesP() in the color black=(0,0,0) into the image ... in theory this should cancel out all the existing white lines. I am not sure how well this will work in practice, maybe someone else has a better idea to get to the result from the binary Image?